# Having problems with referencing and using object from other class in kivy

Tags: python, object, kivy

I am new to python and object oriented programming. I am doing my GUI in kivy, with quite a few pages, screen manager, screens and classes. I am facing problem accessing and updating objects from different screens and classes.

I think its the way of referencing the objects id which I'm not getting it right.

Would be really very grateful if someone kind enough can guide and help me. Thank you. Sorry for the code, tried to shorten as much as i can.

I am having problem updating the background color of id **process_available**.

which i tried to reference using this line (not sure if i am right) -> **WindowWithMenuTemplate.process_available.background_color = 1, 1, 1, 1**

which is from class **ProcessIndicatorTemplate**
inside **WindowWithMenuTemplate**
attached to **AccWindow** screen
onto **WindowManager** screen maanger.

the error it is returning is

```
WindowWithMenuTemplate.process_available.background_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
 AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'background_color'
```

in python

```
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import requests
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class AccWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AccWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        acc0_user_record = ObjectProperty(None)

    def acc0_login_btn(self, acc_no):
        # i shorten this function as an illustration to ask, else the code is very long. the rest of codes is 
        # working except this specific line is not working below which i am trying to change another class object 
        # background color when i press this login_btn
        WindowWithMenuTemplate.process_available.background_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
        # this line below works
        self.acc0_user_record.background_color = 0, 0, 0, 0

class WindowWithMenuTemplate(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WindowWithMenuTemplate, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        process_available = ObjectProperty(None)
        process_in_automation = ObjectProperty(None)
        process_in_manual = ObjectProperty(None)

class BackgroundColorLabelTemplate(Label):
    pass

class ProcessIndicatorTemplate(Label):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        wm = WindowManager()
        return wm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

in kyvy

```
<WindowManager>:
    LoginWindow:
    HomeWindow:
    ExecutionWindow:
    OrdersWindow:
    AccWindow:
    SettingsWindow:

<HomeWindow>:
    name: "home_window"
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:

<ExecutionWindow>:
    name: "execution_window"
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:

<OrdersWindow>:
    name: "orders_window"
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:

<AccWindow>:
    name: "acc_window"
    acc0_user_record: acc0_user_record
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 4
        padding: 10, 10, 10, 10
        spacing: 10,10
        size_hint: 1, 0.834
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label:
                text: "Acc 0"
                font_size: 11
            GridLayout:
                cols: 3
                BackgroundColorLabelTemplate:
                    id: acc0_user_record
                    text: ""
                    font_size: 11
                TextInput:
                    id: acc0_user_input
                    text: ""
                    font_size: 11
                    multiline: False
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                Button:
                    text: "Submit"
                    font_size: 11
                    disabled: True if acc_win_toggle_off.state == "down" and acc_win_toggle_on.state == "normal" else False
                    on_release:
                        root.acc0_login_btn("0")
                        acc_win_toggle_off.state = "down"
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                Button:
                    text: "Logout"
                    font_size: 11
                    disabled: True if acc_win_toggle_off.state == "down" and acc_win_toggle_on.state == "normal" else False
                    on_release:
                        root.acc0_logout_btn()
                        acc_win_toggle_off.state = "down"

<SettingsWindow>:
    name: "settings_window"
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:

<WindowWithMenuTemplate>:
    process_available: process_available
    process_in_automation: process_in_automation
    process_in_manual: process_in_manual

    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top":1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: False
            ActionPrevious:
                title: "My"
                with_previous: True
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "home_window"
            ActionButton:
                text: "Execution"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "execution_window"
            ActionButton:
                text: "Orders"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "orders_window"
            ActionGroup:
                text: "Options"
                mode: "spinner"
                ActionButton:
                    text: "Acc"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "acc_window"
                ActionButton:
                    text: "Settings"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "settings_window"
                ActionButton:
                    text: "Logout"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "login_window"

    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.9, "top": 0.922}
        cols: 3
        ProcessIndicatorTemplate:
            id: process_available
        ProcessIndicatorTemplate:
            id: process_in_automation
        ProcessIndicatorTemplate:
            id: process_in_manual

<BackgroundColorLabelTemplate>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

<ProcessIndicatorTemplate>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must access property values at the instance level, not the class level, so

```
WindowWithMenuTemplate.process_available.background_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
```

causes an error. One way to fix that is to reference the instance by adding an `id` to the `WindowWithMenuTemplate` in the `kv`:

```
<AccWindow>:
    name: "acc_window"
    acc0_user_record: acc0_user_record
    WindowWithMenuTemplate:
        id: wwmt
```

Then use that in the python code:

```
def acc0_login_btn(self, acc_no):
    # i shorten this function as an illustration to ask, else the code is very long. the rest of codes is
    # working except this specific line is not working below which i am trying to change another class object
    # background color when i press this login_btn
    # WindowWithMenuTemplate.process_available.background_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
    self.ids.wwmt.process_available.background_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
    # this line below works
    self.acc0_user_record.background_color = 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much John. That shed some light for me on object referencing in Kivy! it was giving me some headache as I'm not sure how to access variables and objects across multiple screens..

Comment: If you are reaching across `Screens`, the `get_screen()` method of `ScreenManager` is handy.

Comment: Great suggestion John, Thank you! I didn't know that exists even after searching quite abit on how to reference across screens. :x

Answer (score 0):

Excited to try it at night after my work. Can I confirm with you, if this will work.

While in a screen and in order for me to access my other screens objects across screens. under Kivy ScreenManager, i will give all screens an id and through:

```
self.manager.get_screen('screen name').ids.<desired widget id>.<desired method or properties>
or
self.root.manager.get_screen('screen name').ids.<desired widget id>.<desired method such as def XXX() or properties such as text>
```

or

```
app = App.get_running_app()
app.root.manager.get_screen('screen name').ids.<desired widget id>.<desired method such as def XXX() or properties such as text>
```

this is what I'm thinking now. will try around with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

in case this helps anyone, i found the solution below.

```
app = App.get_running_app()
app.root.get_screen(app.root.current).ids.wwmt.ids.process_available.background_color = [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

bascally root gets your screenmanager.
get_screen refers to that screen widget, then on each current widget, use ids to get the internal ids, then reference to that required widget, and on it use ids again so and so forth until you reach the property you want to amend or the method.

this is my understanding, not sure if im totally right.